# Informatica cloud (IICS) not loading the fields from SQL server where field name starts with numeric (10CL_xyz)

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter, informatica-cloud

Informatica cloud is not loading the data into sql server where sql server field name is 10CI_Reason.

it is showing the below error

```
 Not all input columns presented in target TMP_CondPolicyIndex_AIL. Target columns are ActionFlag, 
 ZipCode, StreetName, SystemCode, FileCode, PolicyNumber, AddressType, _10CI_Reason. Missed columns 
 are _10CI_Reason.
```

IICS is taking underscore in the begining (_10CI_Reason) where sql server does not have any spaces.
Helpful solutions are appriciated.

Comment: Looks like you cant write into such columns. I can think of is, load the data into a stage table and then use `INSERT INTO original table as select * from stg_table;` to insert into the original table. Make sure stg table and target table have same definition.

Comment: Hi Koushik i tried with above insert but still it is not loading.

Comment: Hi Koushik i tried with above insert but still it is not loading. I had inserted with each and every values in both the tables but still gettting the same error. if there is any other alternate way please let me know. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Insert executed as Post-SQL should work. Just make sure you execute it correctly. If you get any error, please post the details.

Comment: Let me add more details, pls name columns of stg table starting with alphabets and do not use numbers as first character. For e.g., if you have final target col as `10CI_Reason` then create this column as `xx10CI_Reason`. Actually informatica target column can not start with number. So load into stg first with valid target col name. Then load into final table.